# "Latex warning: "!h" float specifier changed to "ht!" same file, different results

Tags: graphics

[image]So this is really weird

I am trying to compile a tex file, but it resulted in the error:"Latex warning: "!h" float specifier changed to "ht!"

And it failed to compile even though there is no error, only warnings. So I deleted all the lines associated with \inlcudegraphic to see what wrong, but it stills failed to compile with the same(I think?) warning metioned above. So I opened a new tex file, and it compiled smoothly. I even copied pasted the code from my new tex file to my old tex file and still the messages appeared and it failed to compile. So I guess that means it shouldn't be anything wrong with my code per se?

I have already tried thrashing the AUX file option, but to no avail. I checked my source directory and it seems in addition to the usual associated files there is a file titled "untitled.sysctex.(busy)" and I'm sure it has something to do with my problem.
[image]

Comment: What you mean by "failed to compile"? The message you quote is no error but a warning, it means that the float positioning algorithm didn't manage to place the float according to your instructions and had to open up to other options.

Comment: It is not an error and will not stop latex making the pdf.  The warning is simply telling you that the constraint you specified `[h]` was not achievable so latex is changing it to `[ht]` to make it possible to position the float. It is specific to that document, just adding a single character anywhere could change the page breaking and make that warning come or go. It is almost always wrong to use `!` or to use `h` on its own so you should not normally get the warning.

Comment: Yeah, again I believe it has nothing to do with my code since I copy paste the same code to a new document and it compiled perfectly.

Comment: It is very hard to debug if you only show the code and error message as an image, but the error dialog that you show does not appear to be from the document that you show. Firstly it warns about two figure using `[!ht]` then it ends at the `*` prompt which means that there is no `\end{document}` in the file so tex has read past the end of the file and is waiting from more input. The document in your image has no figures and does have `\end{document}`

Comment: But it is! That is why it is weird. As I said, I copy past my code to a new file it compiled successful. So I assume it is not because of any code. BTW, I can only do image because texshop doesn't allow me to copy the error messages.

Comment: the warnings shown can not possibly be from the document shown. I note you are using "untitled" your editor may get less confused if you save the document to some named file before running. texshop will allow you to copy the error messages, tex always writes them to the log file you can copy them from there.